# Is there a simple way to a list of input event handler hooks subscribed to setwindowshookex?

Tags: c#, hook, user32

Wasn't a useful method mentioned at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

beyond C# simple, I am also wondering if there is *any* way to get a list of the subscribed event handlers.

Comment: I can imagine why the OS wouldn't want app processes or threads calling or inter-competing event handler hooks, I might delete this question.

Comment: The callback you install with SetWindowsHookEx doesn't have anything to do with an event.   Windows doesn't support a way to enumerate installed hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a few more searches into the question, it looks Hans P.'s comment describes it